# jQuery .NOT() $(this) or $(this).parent()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code and I'm trying to stop if from firing the `.hide()` on two occasions, currently using `.not()`. The two occasions are:

- $(this).parent().closest(".HoverChild")
  and
- $(this).children(".HoverChild")

**EDIT:** Because it's not using the second `$(this)` it's hiding the child element then showing it again.

```js
$(".HoverContainer").on("hover click",function (e) { 

  $('.HoverChild').not(
    $(this).parent().closest(".HoverChild"),
    $(this).children(".HoverChild")
  ).hide();

  if ($(".HoverContainer").is(e.target)){e.stopPropagation();}

$(this).children('.HoverChild').stop(true,true).slideToggle(100);

 });
$("body").on("hover click",function (e){ if (!$(".HoverContainer").is(e.target) && $(".HoverContainer").has(e.target).length === 0) { $(".HoverContainer").children('.HoverChild').hide(); }});
$(".HoverChild").on("hover click",function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

```css
html, body{ WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="HoverContainer" style="Float:Left;">
  <img src="" alt="View Categories" style="width:20px;height:20px;">
  <div class="HoverChild" style="display: none;">
    <ol class="top-nav" >
  <li class="HoverContainer" >Parent
          <ul class="HoverChild" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</span>
```

Your help on this would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

glenn2223

Comment: What part isn't working? whats the question. I didn't know you could have multiple objects in `.not()` like that, wouldn't you need to use `.add()`

Comment: @atmd Sorry. I've now edited it. How would I use .add()?

Comment: as per BenM's answer

Comment: @atmd Thanks .add() has been a success. What would I do without you guys(and gals)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) only accepts a single argument. You have three options to achieve what you would like. The first one is to pass an array into the `not()` function as follows:

```
$('.HoverChild').not([
    $(this).parent().closest('.HoverChild'),
    $(this)
]).hide();
```

Alternatively, you need to filter down the results after the first parameter of the `not()` function is evaluated. You can either do that by chaining another `not()` function to the filter, for example:

```
$('.HoverChild').not( $(this).parent().closest('.HoverChild') )
                .not ($(this) )
                .hide();
```

Or you can combine `$(this).parent().closest('.HoverChild')` and `$(this)` into a single jQuery collection using [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/), and then evaluate `not()` on that:

```
var $not = $(this).parent().closest('.HoverChild').add( $(this) );
$('.HoverChild').not($not).hide();
```

Comment: I think if you can pass in an array, you might also be able to use jquery merge(); I will check.

Comment: @lharby You *can* pass in an array - that's what the first part of my answer says... `The first one is to pass an array into the not() function as follows:`

Comment: Yes I agree and you gave a very comprehensive answer.

Comment: @BenM The first and second theories don't work (tried them already and also just tried them on my snippet). No idea why. But the .add() has worked. Thanks sooooo much, I've been scratching my head for a few days now. **+1,000,000 if I could.**